# Predict data of next 2 months through data of last 10 months

Tags: r

I have data of last 10 months in CSV file through which I want to predict data of next 2 months using R.Kindly help I am a beginner.
What i have did yet is :

1. Read data from file.
2. Put half data in a variable named 'train' and other half in 'test'.
3. `Model<-lm(data=train)`
4. `prediction<-predict(Model,newdata=test)`

Kindly help if i am on the right track or not? Kindly elaborate. Thanks in advance.Help will be a great favor as its an office task and no one is here to help.

Comment: So... did it work? IMHO appropriate model heavily depends on your data and process it is coming from. If a trend is linear, then it might work. Just don't predict weather this way:-)

Comment: If everything was so easy, no one would ever need to employ a statistician. I would start [validating your fitted model](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/rdiagnostics.html) before even thinking of any predioction

Comment: Thank You so much for your concern. Kindly suggest some reading material which can help me for this purpose.

Comment: Press on the link i've provided above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to forecast from only 10 months of (monthly) data be aware that any model you come up with is not going to be very precise since this is such a small number of observations. Also, I would not bother with splitting your data into training and test sets; 10 months of data is pretty sparse even for training a model. On top of this, without a couple of years of data (minimum), it's not possible to decompose the series into different components (seasonal, cyclical, trend, error). However, you can certainly play around with some of the different modelling facilities of R and you might be able to identify a general trend or pattern in the data. For example:

```
install.packages("forecast",dependencies=TRUE)
library(forecast)
t0 <- as.Date("2013-06-01",format="%Y-%m-%d")  # Initial month
##
# Some data
set.seed(1000)
Data <- data.frame(
        Date=seq.Date(from=t0,by='month',length.out=10), 
        Value=(cumsum(rnorm(10,3,2))+rnorm(10))
)
##
tData <- ts(Data$Value,
        start=c(2013,6),
        frequency=12
)
##
# Try using auto.arima() to fit an autoregressive model
Mod1 <- auto.arima(tData)
summary(Mod1)
# 2 period forecast
plot(forecast(Mod1, h=2))
##
## Or ets() for an exponential smoothing state space model
Mod2 <- eta(tData)
summary(Mod2)
# 2 period forecast
plot(forecast(Mod2, h=2))
```